# MySQL: Create a Foreign key without an Index

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, foreign-keys, database-indexes

Is it possible to have a foreign key without an index in MySQL 5.6.34? I want that because I created a nullable column in **20M** rows with a foreign key to another table. As this is a new feature, only the new rows MAY have this column filled with an actual value, and as you may expect, **the cardinality of that index becomes horrible**. So, for most of the time, using that index is actually a bad idea. The problem: I have tons of queries that shares this same restriction:

```
[...] from large_table where tenant_id = ? and nullable_foreign_key_with_index is null and [...]
```

The issue? MySQL thinks that it's a good idea to use an **index_merge/intersect strategy** for query resolution. In this case MySQL would do 2 queries in parallel: one with `tenant_id` (which uses a valid and good index) and another one with `nullable_foreign_key_with_index` which is bad, almost a "full table scan in parallel" given that the cardinality of this index is **<1000** in a table with **>20M** rows. More details about this "problem" in [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/14/the-optimization-that-often-isnt-index-merge-intersection/)

So, what are the pssible solutions? Given that MySQL "forces" a foreign key to have an index attached:

1. **Drop the foreign key and the index.** This is bad, because in the case of a bug in the app we may compromise the referential integrity.
2. **FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; Drop index; FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1.** This is bad, because even that the foreign key still exists, MySQL doesn't validade the column anymore to check if the value actually exists. Is that a bug?
3. **Use query hints in all existing queries to make sure that we are only using the old and efficient "tenant_id_index"**. This is bad because I have to hunt down all existing queries and also remember to use it again when news queries are built.

So, how can I say: *"MySQL, don't bother creating an index for this foreign key, but keep validating it's content in the related table, which is indexed by primary key anyway"*. Am I missing something? The best idea so far is to remove the foreign key and just believe that the app is working as expected, which probably it is, but this would start a classic discussion about having constraints in APP vs DATABASE. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this query:

```
from large_table
where tenant_id = ? and
      nullable_foreign_key_with_index is null and [...]
```

Just add the index `large_table(tenant_id, nullable_foreign_key_with_index)`.

MySQL should use this index for the table.

I'm pretty sure you can do this backwards (I would be 100% sure if the comparison were to anything other than `NULL`, but I'm pretty sure MySQL does the right thing with `NULL` as well.)

```
large_table(nullable_foreign_key_with_index, tenant_id)
```

And MySQL will recognize that this index works for the foreign key and not create any other index.

Comment: That would be my suggestion. Add a composite index. +10

Comment: Your advice did work! Thanks! But, why doing it backwards would be any good? Given that the cardinality of the leftmost column (nullable_foreign_key_with_index) is very low?

Comment: @IsraelFonseca . . . The cardinality doesn't make much of a difference.  The index covers the `where` clause -- that is, all the keys are used.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I did a test with both indexes and surprisingly for me, both had the same performance. Why is that? Isn't the *leftmost* column used as a reference for the binary search? If that was the case, the low cardinality should almost invalidate the binary search, effectively doing a "full table scan". Am I right? Or what am I missing about how indexing works?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I've answered myself. If the two columns are referenced in query, it doesn't matter. It would, only if just one appeared. The actual index is "composed" together with all the selected columns, so binary search work on top of it without problems if the where clause have all that columns to generate the lookup key.

Answer (score 4):

Q: How can I say: *"MySQL, don't bother creating an index for this foreign key, but keep validating it's content in the related table, which is indexed by primary key anyway"*

A: No can do. InnoDB requires a suitable index to support the enforcement of  foreign key constraint.

Consider the flip side of it... if we are going to DELETE a row in the parent table, then InnoDB needs to check the foreign key constraint.

That means InnoDB needs to check the contents of the child table, to find rows that have a specific value in foreign key column.  Essentially equivalent to

```
SELECT ... FROM child_table c WHERE c.foreign_key_col = ?
```

And to do that, InnoDB requires that there be an index on child_table that has `foreign_key_col` as the leading column.

The options suggested in the question (disabling or dropping the foreign key) will work because then InnoDB isn't going enforce the foreign key. But as noted in the question, what this means is that the foreign key isn't enforced. Which defeats the purpose of the foreign key. The application code could be responsible for enforcing referential integrity, or we could write some ug-gghhh-ly triggers (no, we don't want to go there).

---

As Gordon already noted in his (as usual excellent) answer... the problem isn't really dropping the index on the foreign key column. The *actual* problem is the inefficient execution plan. And the most likely fix for that is to make sure a more suitable index is available.

Composite indexes are the way to go. An index like this:

```
... ON child_table (foreign_key_col,tenant_id,...)
```

would satisfy the requirement of the foreign key, an index with the foreign key column as a leading column. And drop the (now redundant) index on just the singleton foreign_key_col.

This index could also be used to satisfy the query that's using a horrible index merge access plan. (Verify with EXPLAIN.)

Also, consider adding columns (such as foreign_key_col) to the index that has tenant_id as the leading column

```
... ON child_table (tenant_id,...,foreign_key_col,...)
```

and drop the redundant index on the singleton tenant_id col.

Comment: About the composite index advice, I created, without removing any other index, the suggested `index_new(tenant_id, foreign_key_col)` index and... well it worked. Not because it's using this `index_new`, but because it's using the older one column index `index_tenant_id`. And I didn't get that (but I'm glad that's enough for my problem). Why having this composite index is enough for the optimizer to giveup from using the `index_merge` with the `index_tenant_id` and the `index_foreign_key_col` or even using the `index_new` with the "awful" `index_foreign_key_col`?

Comment: After some thinking, I answered (partially) myself: using the composite index would be better because it would already have the good cardinality column (tenant_id) and the associated 'foreign_key_col' which is part of the "where statement". That makes sense, but why the optimizer went with the "vanilla" `index_tenant_id` instead?

Comment: @IsraelFonseca:  The optimizer may have gone for the shorter (smaller) index. The optimizer discovered there wasn't a "covering" index for the query, so the access plan couldn't avoid visiting pages in the underlying table. With `tenant_id = const` predicate being selective, then use an index. If the statistics told the optimizer that the `fk IS NULL` was not very selective i.e. more than 10% or 20% of the rows would satisfy that condition, an index wouldn't cut back the number of page visits to the underlying table. (This isn't a specific diagnosis. I'm only offering conjecture.)

Comment: @IsraelFonseca: with the composite index `on t (tenant_id,fk_col)` defined, the index `on t (tenant_id)` (singleton column) is redundant. If we dropped the redundant index, then MySQL would use the composite index. (Any query that could make use of the index on the  singleton tenant_id column can also make use of a composite index (that has tenant_id as the leading column.)

Answer (score 0):

Summary:  Almost always it is better to have a composite index instead of depending on "index merge intersect".

If both columns are tested with `=` (or `IS NULL`), it does not matter which order the columns are in the index definition.  That is, cardinality is irrelevant.